# Using JavaScript to parse RSS feed - Without use of external service?

Tags: javascript, ajax, parsing, rss, mediawiki

I've basically been running around all day trying to accomplish one goal, getting the RSS Feeds from two separate sites to display using Javascript. I've pretty much found dozens of sites that accomplish just this, but there are three problems:

1. I don't have the ability to stylize post layouts as much as I want to, this is a problem.
2. Some tacky "RSS2JAVASCRIPT FEED BY ECTXX" is added.
3. They also try to load images - Understand that this is meant to a small news feed on a sidebar with 15 or less characters.

Pretty much, I'd like to be able to fully control the layout of the RSS data meanwhile avoiding services, if possible. Here's the layout I've established: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/67842559/Style_test.html - It's utterly important that the Ref= or #?Ref=" is added to the end of each URL, the site linked to needs to see that in order to understand who linked them there (So they can link back to us - A function on their side will pull up a "Back to XXX" image on their site when that is present)

Here's what I figure:

1. It must be *fairly easy* to use Javascript in order parse and set up an RSS Feed for display, given the multitudes "services" doing so.
2. The type of manipulation required to get layouts & linking work as we plan won't work with "services" - We can't just load some external JS file here, we need to do this ourselves.

You need to understand something else, I only "discovered" Javascript yesterday so it's still fairly new to me.

Here's what I ask: How exactly would I do this *without* the use of Google APIs/Some RSS feed service? I'd like the data to be locally handled for several reasons.

I'm operating from MediaWiki software, and so far most Javascript things have run smoothly so here's to another. What should I do in this case? I can't do it given the present limitations.

Answer (score 2):

It's not really possible in pure JS without using an external service. The only alternative is to get the remote feed with the help of a local php script. Then, you can read your local php script instead of the remote feed and do, whatever you like.

But what exactly is the problem of using the Google service?

However, here's a very basic example, using PHP and JS together to read an external feed:

feed.php:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init($_GET['url']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$xml = curl_exec($ch);
header("Content-Type: text/xml");
echo $xml;
curl_close($ch);
exit;
```

The Javascript (using jQuery):

```
function readFeed() {
    var feedURL = "http://an.example/feed.xml";

    $.get("feed.php?url=" + feedURL, function(data) {
        // Do, whatever you like...
    });
};
```

This could be extended by string filtering, etc. (to avoid XSS, etc.).

Comment: I'll be honest - I can't exactly figure out how that all works. I was only a basic designer for the site until I was asked to look into posting news feed on our main page. Every "guide" I've found regarding the subject with Google doesn't match it's "current" version - Google changed their layout since they were written so I'm clueless. If somebody could fill me in, I just don't seem to get it.

Comment: I can just recommend to get the remote feed via php (or any other serverside language). I've added an example.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't run PHP on site as I don't have admin privileges - Though I can get the admins to install it as an extension, though there's no telling how MediaWiki will handle that. I guess it could be held on the server and not on the Wiki itself. An example would be helpful, this is all new to me.

Comment: MediaWiki is PHP based. Furthermore, PHP was just an example. But if you don't want to use external services, you must read the external feeds locally with a serverside scripting language.

Comment: I understand Mediawiki is PHP based, though I'm not exactly sure how that would translate into acceptable code by MediaWiki - Unless it allows you to install anything as an extension? That's why I said it might be best to have it operate not on the wiki, but on the server. Here's another stupid question: How would I go about displaying and stylizing that? As far as programming I only know Ruby and offline C#.